# how to join two differrent table into single table in sql?

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables like:

```
table-1

name  closedid
rere    4
trtr    5
ewew    6
```

And

```
table-2
name  openedid 
rere    6
trtr    7
ytyt    8 
uyuy    5
```

I want final output like this:

```
name closedid  opened
rere    4         6
trtr    5         7
ytyt    null      8
uyuy    null      5
ewew    6         null
```

What should be the query?

Comment: Please format your text. It's pretty hard to understand the question like this

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp)

Comment: You may get something like `SELECT name, closedid, opened
FROM table-1
FULL OUTER JOIN table-2
ON table-1.name=table-2.name;`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
declare @t table (name varchar(15),  openedid int)
insert into @t (name,openedid) values
('rere',6),
('trtr',7),
('ytyt',8), 
('uyuy',5)
declare @t1 table (name varchar(15),  closedid int)
insert into @t1 (name,closedid) values
('rere',4),
('trtr',5),
('ewew',6)

select isnull(t.name,t1.name) name
      ,t1.closedid
      ,t.openedid 
from @t t 
full outer join @t1 t1 on t.name=t1.name
```

Comment: but in case if the table 1 has 4 names and table 2 has 6 names and in case I will join table1.name=table2.name  then the output will contain only 4 names?

Comment: can you give a sample?